# R: Calculate rowwise lm() over multiple variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, boxplot, lm, rowwise

How can I calculate the row-wise lm() / coeffs of multiple variables in an df, which are stored in columns?

I have this kind of data (just examples):

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- data.frame(trialNumber= 1:10, 
Nr1 = runif(10), 
Nr2 = runif(10), 
Nr3 = runif(10), 
Nr4 = runif(10), 
Nr5 = runif(10), 
Nr6 = runif(10), 
slope = NA)
```

The trialNumber represents each one of a trial where I measured six values directly behind each other.

I managed to plot these data with a linear regression line with boxplots using this code:

```
foo_1 <- reshape2::melt(data = foo, id.vars = "trialNumber", measure.vars = c("Nr1", "Nr2", "Nr3", "Nr4", "Nr5", "Nr6"))

p <- ggplot(data = foo_1) + 
  aes(x = variable,
      y = value) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_jitter(shape = 1, position = position_jitter(0.1)) +
  ylim(0, NA) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, formula = y ~ x, aes(group = 1)) 

print(p)
```

which results in this diagram:

[image]

Now this is the linear regression line of all the trials, but I want the slope (or regression coefficients) row-wise stored in the variable "slope".

In the end I want a df like this:

```
trialnumber | Nr1 | Nr2 | Nr3 | Nr4 | Nr5 | Nr6 | slope
1           | 0.26550866 | 0.2059746|0.93470523|0.4820801|0.8209463|0.47761962|e.g. 0.07
2           | ?   | ?   | ?   | ?   | ?   | ?   |e.g. 3.81
.
.
.
```

How can I achieve this? I already looked into the `apply` function, but I could not figure out how to use this.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed just use `apply`. This only requires that you know the indices of your columns. Here I have specified `2:7`, but for your own data you could get the correct indices by specifying for example `grep("Nr", names(foo))`. You need to make sure the columns are in the correct order in your data frame though, as they are in your example.

```r
foo$slope <- apply(foo[2:7], 1, function(x) coef(lm(x ~ seq(x)))[2])

foo
#>    trialNumber        Nr1       Nr2        Nr3       Nr4       Nr5        Nr6
#> 1            1 0.26550866 0.2059746 0.93470523 0.4820801 0.8209463 0.47761962
#> 2            2 0.37212390 0.1765568 0.21214252 0.5995658 0.6470602 0.86120948
#> 3            3 0.57285336 0.6870228 0.65167377 0.4935413 0.7829328 0.43809711
#> 4            4 0.90820779 0.3841037 0.12555510 0.1862176 0.5530363 0.24479728
#> 5            5 0.20168193 0.7698414 0.26722067 0.8273733 0.5297196 0.07067905
#> 6            6 0.89838968 0.4976992 0.38611409 0.6684667 0.7893562 0.09946616
#> 7            7 0.94467527 0.7176185 0.01339033 0.7942399 0.0233312 0.31627171
#> 8            8 0.66079779 0.9919061 0.38238796 0.1079436 0.4772301 0.51863426
#> 9            9 0.62911404 0.3800352 0.86969085 0.7237109 0.7323137 0.66200508
#> 10          10 0.06178627 0.7774452 0.34034900 0.4112744 0.6927316 0.40683019
#>          slope
#> 1   0.07008128
#> 2   0.12126747
#> 3  -0.01554811
#> 4  -0.07855978
#> 5  -0.02329221
#> 6  -0.08106554
#> 7  -0.12697229
#> 8  -0.07226543
#> 9   0.03072317
#> 10  0.04405726
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bar <- reshape2::melt(foo[,-8], id.var = "trialNumber")

#create x values
#this assumes that the column names are exactly as shown
bar$variable <- as.integer(bar$variable)

library(nlme)
fit <- lmList(value ~ variable | trialNumber, data = bar)

#this assumes trial numbers are sorted in foo
foo$slope <- coef(fit)[, "variable"]
```